# which readers honor -webkit-transform CSS property?

Tags: epub, css

I have got an ebook (in epub format) of a popular Italian series for children. However, I cannot browse it with my usual Android ebook reader (Moon+ Reader Pro) because formatting is quite wrong: for example the text is so big that a screen shows ten words or so. Sigil however displays the text fine in the preview. I checked the source code, and I noticed that for each page there are specific CSS styles. Here there is a sample:

```
.t18 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
    transform: scale(0.25);
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: visible;
}
#t1_18{left:315px;bottom:32px;letter-spacing:3.1px;}
#t2_18{left:108px;bottom:663px;}
#t3_18{left:108px;bottom:631px;}
#t4_18{left:108px;bottom:599px;}
#t5_18{left:254px;bottom:599px;}
#t6_18{left:108px;bottom:567px;}
#t7_18{left:125px;bottom:563px;letter-spacing:3.3px;}
```

Here there is the text for a snippet of the page, and its rendering:

```
<div id="p18" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; background-color: white; width: 614px; height: 805px;">
<div id="pg18Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
<div id="pg18" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><img height="805" id="pdf18" src="../Images/18.png" style="width:614px; height:805px; -moz-transform:scale(1); z-index: 0;" width="614"/></div>
<div class="t18 s1_18" id="t1_18">14</div>
<div class="t18 s2_18" id="t2_18">– Senza dimenticare la scaletta per la presen-</div>
<div class="t18 s2_18" id="t3_18">tazione – annotò Colette. – Oh, ci sono ancora</div>
<div class="t18 s3_18" id="t4_18">tantissimissimi</div>
<div class="t18 s2_18" id="t5_18">dettagli da sistemare!</div>
<div class="t18 s4_18" id="t6_18">–</div>
<div class="t18 s5_18" id="t7_18">Per mille bielle sbiellate</div>
<div class="t18 s4_18" id="t8_18">,</div>
<div class="t18 s2_18" id="t9_18">per riuscire a orga-</div>
<div class="t18 s2_18" id="ta_18">nizzare tutte queste cose avremo bisogno di</div>
```

[image: rendering of part of the page]

My guess is that I need a reader which supports -webkit-transform-origin , -ms-transform-origin, -webkit-transform and -ms-transform. Do you know of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is either:

- in the specific software (Moon + Reader Pro): maybe it has some bugs
  in parsing .css
- or in the screen size of your tablet: the scale 0.25
  is too big for it

The css you provided looks reasonable:

`-webkit-` tags are added [for compatibility with iOS readers](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-transform-origin), because those readers won't display an epub properly without this tag

`-ms-` tags are added [for compatibility with Windows readers](https://htmlcss.fandom.com/wiki/-ms-transform-origin)

As your platform is Android, the first 2 tags in the following CSS should be ignored:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
-ms-transform: scale(0.25);
transform: scale(0.25);
```

So your reader should parse the simple `transform` tag.

I'd advice you to:

1. Try to change the `scale(0.25)` to `scale(0.15)` or so and see if the 
   result is better.
2. Write to the support of Moon + Reader Pro app and ask if there can
   be a problem in the app when rendering your specific epub.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to change scale to 0.1 for all three transforms tags: Sigil shows the words in the right position but really tiny, which is expected, but in Moon+ Reader Pro there was no effect. I guess the only option is to ask the developer of Moon+ Reader Pro. Thanks again!